# I recently solved a problem where a tenis ball is kept on a basketball and basket ball is at some height from the ground

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, collision

. When the system is released the tennis bounces back to a larger height  than it was before. what is the reason for this? I mean the problem assumes elastic collisions. How can the tennis ball rise to greater height?

Comment: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2UHS883_P60)

Answer (score 1):

If you just dropped the tennis ball on the ground, it would bounce up to the same height from which you released it (because the collisions are elastic, i.e. energy-conserving). That is the case in which the ground is just sitting still.  But what if ground were moving upward when the tennis ball hit it?  Obviously, the tennis ball would rebound higher then.  But that is essentially what happens with the basketball: because it's so much heavier than the tennis ball, it basically looks like the ground--it doesn't slow down much when it collides with the tennis ball (we imagine that the basketball was a smidge ahead of the tennis ball, with a little gap between, so that things happen in sequence: first basketball bounces off the ground, second, tennis ball bounces off basketball which is already moving upward).  If the tennis ball is very much lighter than the basketball, it will reach a height nine times that from which it was dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m_1$ be mass of tennis ball, $m_2$ mass of the basketball. Let $r_1$ be radius of tennis ball, $r_2$ radius of basketball.

Suppose the tennis ball is balanced on top of the basketball and the center of the basketball is a height, $h$, above the ground. Then the tennis ball is $r_1+r_2+h$ above the ground.

Then the potential energy is  $$PE=m_2gh+m_1g(h+r_1+r_2)$$

Drop both of them. They hit the ground. Assuming a perfectly elastic collision, all the potential energy becomes kinetic energy of the basketball and the tennis ball.

Let $E_1$ be the kinetic energy of the tennis ball and $E_2$ be the kinetic energy of the basketball.

We have: $PE=E_1+E_2$

$E_1=\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2, E_2=\frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2$

The kinetic energy might not be shared equally.

Let's assume $(r_1+r_2)<<h$ to ease the math.

Then $PE=gh(m_1+m_2)$

Then $E_2=gh(m_1+m_2)-E_1$

The height achieved by the tennis ball will be $h_1=E_1/m_1g$, the basket ball $h_2=E_2/m_2g$.

The ratio of heights is $\frac{h_1}{h_2}=\frac{E_1/m_1}{E_2/m_2}=\frac{m_2E_1}{m_1E_2}$

Average mass of tennis ball is about $m_1=60$grams.

Average mass of a regulation basketball is $625$ grams.

So, knowing nothing about the final kinetic energies, we do know that:

$\frac{h_1}{h_2}\approx \frac{10.42E_1}{E_2}$

So if both balls receive an equal share of the potential energy, it is expected that the tennis ball will reach a height 10 times higher than the basketball.

For the heights to be equal, the basketball would have to receive about 10 times more energy than the tennis ball.

The bounce itself is a bit complex. The momentum reverses, so there's an average force being applied in the transition of momentum from the old value to the new value. Old and new are about the same, but opposite in direction. The balls themselves can be thought of as couple springs undergoing this force. Young's Modulus and Hooke's law should yield some decent approximations for expected share of the force and therefore the energy.

But by the analysis already performed, unless there is significantly unequal share of energy in favor of the basketball, the tennis ball is expected to go higher.

Answer (score 0):

Together, the basketball and the tennis ball have x amount of potential energy. The basketball has much more than the tennis ball because it is much more massive. When they are dropped, that potential energy is converted into kinetic energy. When they hit the ground, the collision is elastic. Therefore, the tennis ball and the basketball together have the same amount of energy that they started with, but now it is all kinetic energy. The direction is reversed (up) because the ground doesn't move and all of the kinetic energy is given back to the system, only in the opposite direction. Now, the tennis ball and the basket ball are separate objects, so when the momentum of the system is reversed, it is all transferred to the tennis ball. Now, the tennis ball has the energy that it started with, plus the energy of the basketball, which gives all of its kinetic energy to the tennis ball because it is an elastic collision. Because of that, the tennis ball has more energy than it started with and bounces higher.

Answer (score 0):

Let me put it all together in simple terms.

1. Consider tennisball-basketball system as a unit - approximated by a point mass at their **center of gravity**.
2. Assuming perfectly elastic collision, the center of gravity must rise to the original height (conservation of total mechanical energy in case of conservative forces.)
3. Now during collision with ground, both the balls will exert force on each other in vertical direction - tennis ball will push basketball downward and the basketball will push tennis ball upward.
4. However, the center of gravity of both the balls has to rise to the original height, thus tennis ball will jump above it's original height whereas basketball will jump only upto a lesser height.